# TCP port "rtps-dd-ut"?

Tags: tcp, port

When I use netstat I see that string instead of a port number. What is this? When I search for it I find a website from which it seems like it is the same as 7401. But I never heard about the fact that you can use strings instead of numbers for ports. I'm searching for detailed explanation of that topic but cannot find it.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/640150/custom-port-names-for-netstat

Comment: awesome, thank you!! looking at /etc/services things become clearer